# Elasticsearch content-type header

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm on of the people stuck with Elastisearch 6.0 problem of enforcing content type.

I'm just trying to play around with the example Shakespeare data set found at
[this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/tutorial-load-dataset.html).

I've seen several people asking about this problem, and I know why the problem exists, but I cant see any way around it.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

This is my curl command, still returning the 406 error:

```
Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported
```

Hope someone has the answer.

Comment: You need to use `-XPOST` when hitting the `_bulk` endpoint. Exactly like shown in the link

Comment: ok, so using their command: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @shakespeare_6.json....... i get two errors "could not resolve host:application and localhost"

Comment: Is your ES server reachable at localhost:9200?

Comment: Yeah, i'm getting a JSON response showing name, cluster name etc.

Comment: curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -XPOST localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @shakespeare_6.json - this is their command, but with space removed from the header and single quotes removed from the url - stops me getting the "could not resolve" errors, but still running into the content-type header issue

Comment: content-type should either be `application/x-ndjson` or `application/json` but not `application/xjson`

Comment: I did edit this comment before you responded, a simple notepad error. Even with json, still the same error.